Execute Shell command after Switching to another user in Python
I am looking for a solution in which I should be able to do following in Python:

Login to a unix system with a generic user (user id/password);
Switch to another user who can not be directly logged into with 'sudo -iu '
Be prompted for password applicable for user in step 1;
Once logged in, fire away certain commands or execute certain shell script;
exit out along with logs.

I have used subprocess as well as paramiko but have not been able to go beyond direct login.
Can any of you please help?

I suggest using pexpect to automate the interactive use of ssh and sudo
